# How to detect all the loops among nodes in Neo4j?

Tags: loops, graph, neo4j, cypher

How to detect all the loops in Neo4j?

If we have two nodes A and B :

A including: A.ID, A.Year, A.Name, and
B including: B.ID, B.Year, B.Name ,

That A.Name and B.Name are related to each other based on A.ID = B.ID, How we can detect all the loops among the nodes that shows A.Name related to B.Name and B.Name related to A.Name (directly or with some nodes in between)?

Comment: How are your nodes labeled, what relationship types do you have, and what node labels are connected by each relationship type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/overview/apoc.nodes/apoc.nodes.cycles/ but it's based on explicit loops, formed by relationships between nodes, not implicit equality associations like `A.ID` and `B.ID` in your example.

The first step would be extract the ID properties of your nodes to a property of a relationship created between each matching pair.

Then you could call `apoc.nodes.cycles`.